# Is there a way to know where is require/resolve tryting to find modules in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a plugin system for a Node.js library and I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to figure out where the "require" and "require.resolve" functions are looking for packages when running some tests. I keep getting errors such as:

```
Cannot find module 'plugin-name' from "index.jS"
```

I know that typically Node.js would look for "node_modules" directories all the way up the hierarchy, but since I'm doing some mocking on my tests things are not that straightforward, so it would be really helpful if I could print some logs or debugging info of the paths Node.js is trying to find packages in.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Isn't it the global "nodepath"?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodepath)

Comment: You could stub the required node module, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747035/how-to-unit-test-a-node-js-module-that-requires-other-modules

Answer (score 1):

I think `module.paths` will probably be most useful. Running locally I get, what I think is a complete array of search paths, which includes the `node_modules` directories all the way up the tree as well as `~/.node_libraries`,  `~/.node_modules`, and `'/usr/local/lib/node'`

The documentation simply say:

> **module.paths**
>   The search paths for the module

There's a pretty good description on the algorithm here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together