# Why can't I properly stub the twilio library with sinon?

Tags: node.js, mocking, twilio, sinon

In my code, I have:

```
function handleMessage() {
  const twilio = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
  let recordings = twilio.recordings(foundConference.RecordingSid);
  console.log('recordings', recordings);
  return recordings.remove();
}
```

And in my stub, I have:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const twilio = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

exports.twilioRecordings = () => {
  console.log('about to stub', twilio.recordings);
  sinon.stub(twilio, 'recordings').returns('here');
  console.log('finished stub', twilio.recordings);

  return;
};
```

However, it doesn't actually create a stubbed function. It's still using the original `recordings` function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to use the stub?

Comment: In my `handleMessage` function, I have `  let recordings = twilio.recordings(foundConference.RecordingSid);`

Comment: I can see that, I meant how have you put the test file together to use the stub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Twilio npm package returns a function which creates a new object on every call](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/lib/index.js#L9), it's [not a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179109/singleton-pattern-in-nodejs-is-it-needed). So your stubbed twilio instance is scoped to the test only.

Also `twilio.recordings` (as all other properties though) [is defined through the getter function in prototype](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/master/lib/rest/Twilio.js#L540), so they are [read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757337/defining-read-only-properties-in-javascript):

```
Object.defineProperty(Twilio.prototype,
  'recordings', {
  get: function() {
    return this.api.account.recordings;
  }
});
```

So, stubbing actual twilio instance have no effect. Except if you [change the instance's prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015693/how-to-set-the-prototype-of-a-javascript-object-that-has-already-been-instantiat), but I don't think it worth doing for just unit testing.

I'd suggest you to refactor your code to put twilio initialization into separate method:

```
function getTwilio() {
   return require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
}
```

Next your `hangleMessage` will look like:

```
function handleMessage() {
  const twilio = this.getTwilio();
  const recordings = twilio.recordings(...);
  ...
}
```

And next, in your test you can stub `getTwilio()` to return stub:

```
const twilioStub = {
    recordings: sinon.stub(),
    remove: sinon.stub()
}
sinon.stub(myAwesomeModule, 'getTwilio').returns(twilioStub);
```

You also can consider using [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require) package:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const mock = require('mock-require');
mock('twilio', () => ({
  recordings: sinon.stub(),
}));
```

Here [is a question about how-to mock dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747035/how-to-unit-test-a-node-js-module-that-requires-other-modules), there might be other helpful libraries to stub required module.

Hope it helps.